# Flag weight notification

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I flag post or comment there is no way to check (if flag weight is not shown in profile) if my flag was accepted or declined.

It would be great to have flag notification, similar to when you get badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't want this, or at least not for every flag, sometimes I find a bunch of things to flag in a row, and I don't think it would be of any use for me to get lots of notifications about which one's were deemed valid or not since by the time I see those notifications I'll probably have forgotten what I flagged and why.

Possibly if there was another tab on my user page where I could see this kind of information when I felt like it, but I think that might be clutter that I'd look at very seldom so I'm not sure if that would be worth it either.

Comment: a separate tab [is requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82137/146482) now