# View pending flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

I would like to see a "my pending flags" page/section developed.

At the minute we can flag questions etc and suggest what is wrong with them but there is no way of knowing whether the flags we have placed have been accepted/rejected. We therefore cannot tell (without looking at flag weight that is, at best, guesswork as to which flag was a + and which was a -) which flags were accepted or rejected

This may page may also allow the user to "unflag" accidentally flagged questions or questions that have been revised.

I think such a page would greatly increase the flagging efficiency of both myself and other users.

Comment: possibel duplicate : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81555/flag-weight-notification

Comment: @Stecya Not a dupe - I am asking to have a tab(or page) added to my user profile.

Comment: I'll +1 for this. This might also give me the option to "unflag" as well.

Comment: @tombull89 Added to question :)

Comment: @Myles, thanks. I was considering opening a meta request to be able to unflag (or change flag reason) but I've just added it on to here. Not sure how Mod/10k tools would show changed flags but we'll have to see what happens.

Comment: This would be great in combination with http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16720/155528

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flagging summary page now shows how many flags waiting for review and other stats

[image: summary]

We also show you a full list of all the posts you flagged.

Comment: Is this going to be moved to all sites? Noticed it isn't present on Design Beta.

Comment: @RKS unless you have a flag that's been marked as helpful, the link won't be seen. You can, however, access the page from `http://<site>/users/flag-summary/<userid>`

Comment: Ah. So I'm not helpful. lol Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @RKS ah no problem.. keep flagging :-)