# Feature Request: Ability to Edit/Delete Flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View pending flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82137/view-pending-flags)

I just flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912480/different-asp-net-versions-on-one-iis-process) as off-topic and indicated that it should belong on serverfault, however after some consideration I realized that maybe it should actually be on webmasters. I would like to be able to edit my flag accordingly, however SO does not allow me to do so. I know that I've encountered this issue in the past more than once, which is what leads me to this feature request.

Here's what I envision:

On the Flagging Summary page, add an "edit" link next to the flag summary on a per-item basis that will allow the flagger to edit his/her flag.

**UPDATE**

The more I think about this I also realize it would be helpful to have a "delete" link for flags as well. I can think of several times in which the following has occurred:

1. OP posts his/her question with insufficient detail.
2. I flag OP's question as "not a real question."
3. OP updates question, providing more detail.
4. Mod sees my flag, looks at OP's question, and marks my flag as invalid.
5. My flag weight suffers.

Ideally it'd be nice if the following could occur:

1. OP posts his/her question with insufficient detail.
2. I flag OP's question as "not a real question."
3. OP updates question, providing more detail.
4. I delete my flag *before a moderator reviews it*.
5. My flag weight is unchanged.

Obviously if a moderator reviews my flag before I delete it then I'm SOL.

Comment: With regards to your update, many of us actually look back at when you flagged and all of events that transpire since then, so we'd usually notice that you flagged when it was actually a problem. That'd strike me as a valid flag, myself. I think that would be a preferable result than to withdraw the flag completely. No comment on how Stack Overflow specifically handles it, though, since they have a much different beast due to the volume.

Comment: @Grace Note unfortunately that is not always the case, as I've had such flags marked as invalid.

Comment: Which is indeed unfortunate, Brian, and why my preference is that we shouldn't change the mechanisms of flagging, but rather see what can be done to avoid that kind of dismissal. Being able to delete a flag, as your final sentence notes, still doesn't change the problem of this happening.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is an edge case too far. A moderator would see the flag and think "yes this question is off topic but should be migrated to Webmasters". They'll do the migration and dismiss your flag as valid. Job done, everybody happy.

Comment: Please see my update to the question - I added another use case.