# Show my flagged items inline in question view

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface

It would be very helpful if, when I am looking at a question, I could see items that I have flagged in the past -- the question, answers, and comments. I know I can see [a list of my flags from my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82137/view-pending-flags), but I am referring to the ability to see them inline, while looking at the question page itself.

Often, I stumble across the same posts or comments more than once. I don't want to flag a problem post or comment repeatedly, because that wastes my flags and the moderators' time. So, if I have a flag pending, I should be able to see that.

Possible solutions:

1. Perhaps change the pop-up flag reasons dialog to say, "You have already flagged this post/comment."
2. Highlight the word "flag" (for posts) or show a red flag icon without hovering (for comments) in the inline view.
3. Both (1) and (2) -- my preference and suggested fix.

Note: the same thing should happen for currently pending flags and for rejected or disputed flags.

**Edit:** A particularly good use case for this is when cleaning up obsolete, chatty, or rude comments with a lot of back-and-forth. It's easy to lose track of which ones have been flagged when there are several to clean up. I flagged 8 such comments on one question recently, and wouldn't be surprised if I double-flagged at least one of them.

Comment: Note: (1) is what the sites do now with Close votes. (2) is what they do with up/down votes. Neither fits perfectly for the flag links, which are textual in some contexts and graphical in others. Thus, (3) seems like the best fit.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212784/162102

Comment: @MonicaCellio You're right, that is related, though a bit less detailed. I would love to see this implemented...

Comment: Yeah, implementing this would solve that; the other question is a more-specific use case that currently has no good answer.  I'm tired of getting smacked with "you flagged this already" on stuff I flagged *months* ago and the flag was ignored or declined, and that was hundreds of flags ago. :-(